# Example: Algebraic Multiplicity vs Geometric Multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples, spectral-theory

Is there a simple example of a matrix having an eigenvalue whose geometric multiplicity is strictly smaller than its algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_multiplicity#Algebraic_multiplicities) has a fairly straightfoward example.

Comment: Think about a nonzero nilpotent matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
As $\chi_A(t) = t^2$, $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$, but geometric multiplicity $1$.

Answer (score 5):

The matrices having at least one eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity smaller than its algebraic multiplicity are **exactly** the non-diagonalizable ones.
The comments and answer illustrate this: non-zero nilpotent matrices are examples of non-diagonalizable matrices (but there are many other examples !).